# Hacer la llamada a un metodo con un for js

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

```
const app1 = new App("16000", "5 ESTRELLAS", "900MB");
const app2 = new App("1000", "4 ESTRELLAS", "400MB");
const app3 = new App("6000", "4.5 ESTRELLAS", "A00MB");
const app4 = new App("23000", "4.8 ESTRELLAS", "1GB");
const app5 = new App("900", "5 ESTRELLAS", "250MB");
const app6 = new App("17", "3.7 ESTRELLAS", "522MB");
const app7 = new App("42981", "2.9 ESTRELLAS", "723MB");

document.write(`
${app1.appInfo()} <br>
${app2.appInfo()} <br>
${app3.appInfo()} <br>
${app4.appInfo()} <br>
${app5.appInfo()} <br>
${app6.appInfo()} <br>
${app7.appInfo()} <br>
`);
```

alguien sabe como hacer esa parte del código con un bucle? yo lo he estado intentando pero no me sale aun.

Tengo esto:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    document.write(`
    app${i}.appInfo() <br>
    `);
}
```

Pero el problema es que esto solo interpreta la i, el resto de la linea la interpreta como si fueran simples string. Me muestra:

```
app1.appInfo()

app2.appInfo()

app3.appInfo()

app4.appInfo()

app5.appInfo()

app6.appInfo()

app7.appInfo()
```

¿Cómo tendría que hacer para que interprete todo el conjunto?
Dejo el metodo appInfo para que se entienda como debería ser la salida.

```
appInfo(){
        return `
        Descargas: <b>${this.descargas}</b><br>
        Puntuación: <b>${this.puntuacion}</b><br>
        Peso: <b>${this.peso}</b><br>
        `
    }
```

Comment: añadelos a un array, y haces el bucle

Comment: Si estas usando como constante solo 7 apps, no veo problema de que lo dejes como esta inicialmente. Si fuera dinámico y que la cantidad de Apps depende de lo que recibes desde una API o parametro desde otro componente, valdria la pena crear un bucle for. por lo que veo quieres refactorizar y mejoras esteticamente tu código, pero si este código lo vas reutilizar varias veces en tu app, seria lo recomendable. pero si te funciona y cumple el requerimiento, déjalo tal cual, y dejas un comentario para una futura refactorización.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás incurriendo en malas prácticas; en orden de importancia:

1. No deberías crear instancias en variables independientes, porque necesitarás aplicar *"cosas raras"* para acceder a ellas. Lo ideal es tener un arreglo con todas las instancias, porque así tienes un mejor control sobre ellas.

Una de esas *"cosas raras"* puede ser el uso de `eval()`, pero no es recomendable, aunque tú tengas el control de su uso y no haya probabilidades de ataques, el rendimiento no será óptimo.

Otra es declarar cada instancia con `var` para poder acceder a ellas desde contexto global con `window['nombre_de_variable']` que, puede generar otros problemas, probablemente de rendimiento y contexto.

2. No es recomendable el uso de `document.write()` para generar contenido en el navegador. Lo ideal es tener un contenedor y agregar la información con `appendChild()` o [.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) si no quieres complicarte creando otros elementos.

**Solución *"rara"*:**

```js
class App {
    constructor(descargas, puntuacion, peso) {
        this.descargas = descargas;
        this.puntuacion = puntuacion;
        this.peso = peso;
    }
    appInfo() {
        return `
        Descargas: <b>${this.descargas}</b><br>
        Puntuación: <b>${this.puntuacion}</b><br>
        Peso: <b>${this.peso}</b><br>
        `;
    }
}

// Crear instancia usando var en lugar de let o const
// para poder acceder a ellas desde contexto global: window['nombre_de_variable']
var app1 = new App("16000", "5 ESTRELLAS", "900MB");
var app2 = new App("1000", "4 ESTRELLAS", "400MB");
var app3 = new App("6000", "4.5 ESTRELLAS", "A00MB");
var app4 = new App("23000", "4.8 ESTRELLAS", "1GB");
var app5 = new App("900", "5 ESTRELLAS", "250MB");
// Definir con let o const no funciona
let app6 = new App("17", "3.7 ESTRELLAS", "522MB");
const app7 = new App("42981", "2.9 ESTRELLAS", "723MB");


for(let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    // Acceder a instancias desde contexto global
    document.write(window[`app${i}`].appInfo());
}
```

**Solución más adecuada:**

```js
class App {
    constructor(descargas, puntuacion, peso) {
        this.descargas = descargas;
        this.puntuacion = puntuacion;
        this.peso = peso;
    }
    appInfo() {
        // Todo dentro de un párrafo
        return `
        <p>Descargas: <b>${this.descargas}</b><br>
        Puntuación: <b>${this.puntuacion}</b><br>
        Peso: <b>${this.peso}</b></p>
        `;
    }
}
// Definir un arreglo para crear las instancias
const apps = [];

// Insertar cada instancia en el arreglo
apps.push(new App("16000", "5 ESTRELLAS", "900MB"));
apps.push(new App("1000", "4 ESTRELLAS", "400MB"));
apps.push(new App("6000", "4.5 ESTRELLAS", "A00MB"));
apps.push(new App("23000", "4.8 ESTRELLAS", "1GB"));
apps.push(new App("900", "5 ESTRELLAS", "250MB"));
apps.push(new App("17", "3.7 ESTRELLAS", "522MB"));
apps.push(new App("42981", "2.9 ESTRELLAS", "723MB"));

// Obtener contenedor
let preDatos = document.querySelector('#datos');
// Recorrer cada instancia
apps.forEach(app => {
    // Agregar información a contenedor
    preDatos.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', app.appInfo());
});
```

```html
<div id="datos"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas formas de llamar a una function como string, y ninguna es recomendable, te sugiero que cambies la lógica y las instancias de `App` las guardes en un array. De cualquier manera dejo un ejemplo de como hacer esto como lo intentas hacer:

```js
const app1 = () => 1
const app2 = () => 2
const app3 = () => 3
const app4 = () => 4
const app5 = () => 5
const app6 = () => 6
const app7 = () => 7

for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {

  document.write(
    new Function(`return app${i}()`)()
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor sería almacenarlas en un [Arreglo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) o en un [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Puedes almacenar cualquier tipo de objeto en ellas, incluidas las funciones

Este es un ejemplo con **arreglos**

```js
const ownFunctions = [
  () => console.log("Esta es una función"),
  function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
      console.log(`Estoy imprimiendo ${i}`)
  },
  (num=6) =>{
    console.log(`Mi argumento es ${num}`);
  }
];

for (let fun of ownFunctions) {
  fun();
}
```

Aunque probablemente te sirva mejor un **JSON**, dado que puedes tener un mejor control sobre qué función estás llamando.

```js
let myFunctions = {
  sumar: (a = 6, b = 8) => {
    console.log(a + b);
  },
  algo: ()=> {
    console.log("algo");
  },
  tercero: () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
      console.log(`Estoy imprimiendo ${i}`)
    }
  }
};

// Este for recorre las llaves de mi objeto
for (let key in myFunctions) {
  myFunctions[key]()
}

// A esto me refiero con más control

// Como el objeto se relaciona con <llave> - <valor>, yo puedo acceder a mi función mediante la llave, no existe un índice como en el arreglo, lo cual le da mayor facilidad de lectura y de mantenimiento

myFunctions.sumar(7,7);
myFunctions.algo();
```

Recuerda que siempre tienes el método [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) para obtener un arreglo de todas las llaves de tu JSON